# Combine 2 Form inputs to create 1 query parameter

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access form that is asking a user for an operator input from a combo box of > or < and in a separate textbox asking the user to enter in a time. Ultimately the first input will send a parameter to the query that is a combination of the input choice so something like >15. My question is is this poissble? Can I set the value of the > in the first box to be something like the following? Is there another way to do this?

```
>[txtMinutes]
```

or

```
>[Forms]![FormName]![txtMinutes]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic way to do it would be:

```
WHERE (Forms!FormName!txtComparison = "<" AND Minutes < Forms!FormName!txtMinutes) OR
    (Forms!FormName!txtComparison = ">" AND Minutes > Forms!FormName!txtMinutes)
```

An advanced way would be to use the Eval function, I don't know about the performance though:

```
WHERE Eval(Minutes & Forms!FormName!txtComparison & Forms!FormName!txtMinutes) = True
```

Assuming you have your query bound to a continuous form, the best way might be to use visual basic:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , , "Minutes" & _
    Forms!FormName!txtComparison & Forms!FormName!txtMinutes
```